# Wrong values for properties OOP

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I cannot get the correct values from properties set from the following OOP class

```
class person {

    private $defaults = [
        'post_types'        => [],
        'number'            => 1,
        'use_referrers'     => true,
        'in_same_term'      => false,
        'include'           => [],
        'exclude'           => [],
        'taxonomy'          => 'category',
        'include_children'  => true,
        'previous'          => true,
        'boundary_posts'    => false,
        'anchor_text'       => '%anchor',
        'post_link_text'    => '%text',
        'separator'         => '</br>',
        'span_separator'    => '</br>',
        'span_text_prev'    => 'Older post: ',
        'span_text_next'    => 'Newer post: ',
        'span_text_oldest'  => 'Oldest post: ',
        'span_text_newest'  => 'Newest post: ',

    ];

    public $post;
    public $is_referred_post    = false;
    public $is_author_referrer  = false;
    public $is_search_referrer  = false;
    public $is_tax_referrer     = false;


    public function post( $post ) {

        $this->post = get_queried_object();
        return $this->post;

    }

    public function referrers_defaults() {

        //Set is_author_referrer if query_var aq is set
        if( isset( $_GET['aq'] ) ) {

            $this->is_author_referrer = true;

        }

        //Set is_search_referrer if query_var sq is set
        if( isset( $_GET['sq'] ) ) {

            $this->is_search_referrer = true;

        }

        //Set is_tax_referrer if query_var tq is set
        if( isset( $_GET['tq'] ) ) {

            $this->is_tax_referrer = true;

        }

        //Set is_referred_post if the current single post has one of the query_vars in the URL
        if( $this->is_author_referrer || $this->is_search_referrer || $this->is_tax_referrer ) {

            $this->is_referred_post = true;

        }
        return $this;
    }

}
$a = new person();
?><pre><?php var_dump($a); ?></pre><?php
```

This is what I get from the a `var_dump( $a );`

```
object(person)#569 (6) {
  ["defaults":"person":private]=>
  array(18) {
    ["post_types"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["use_referrers"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["in_same_term"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["include"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["exclude"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["include_children"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["previous"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["boundary_posts"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["anchor_text"]=>
    string(7) "%anchor"
    ["post_link_text"]=>
    string(5) "%text"
    ["separator"]=>
    string(5) "
"
    ["span_separator"]=>
    string(5) "
"
    ["span_text_prev"]=>
    string(12) "Older post: "
    ["span_text_next"]=>
    string(12) "Newer post: "
    ["span_text_oldest"]=>
    string(13) "Oldest post: "
    ["span_text_newest"]=>
    string(13) "Newest post: "
  }
  ["post"]=>
  NULL
  ["is_referred_post"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_author_referrer"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_search_referrer"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tax_referrer"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

My problem is this section

```
  ["post"]=>
  NULL
  ["is_referred_post"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_author_referrer"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_search_referrer"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tax_referrer"]=>
  bool(false)
```

`['post']` should not be `NULL`, it should give the values from the current post. If I do `var_dump($a->post());` I do get the post object.

Also, say the following variable is set in the URL `?aq=2`, `["is_author_referrer"]` and `["is_referred_post"]` should return `true`, but they return `false` as you can see from the `var_dump()`.

Why isn't the correct values set to these properties. What am I missing in OOP

Comment: `a->post()` is a method.  The `public $post;` in your object is a property that  contains a null value because it hasn't been initialized with/assigned an actual value.  This is a good lesson in not naming properties the same thing as your methods.  Make your method name something like `getPost()`, or your property something like `$personPost` to save confusion and to make it more readable.  I suggest the former for the semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a->post()` calls the `post` *method*, which is not a property. When you call this method, the method will get a value from somewhere (`get_queried_object`). This value is returned, but also stored in in the `post` property. I think this is the reason why you think the property should be filled. But until you have called the method, the property will remain null.

I wouldn't know the best solution, since I don't know there rest of your application (like, how is this post object constructed, what is `get_queried_object` and from what point is it available, etcetera). Nevertheless I hope I pinpointed the issue for you, and this will help you get to the right solution.

One possible idea is to set `$post` from the constructor instead, but like I said, it depends on other factors whether this will work:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->post = get_queried_object();
}
```

The constructor `__construct` is called when you make a new object.

Comment: I think I get you on this. Will play around with this a little more

Answer (score 0):

I had a misunderstanding about the constructor, and thanks to @GolezTrol I got things working correctly

Here is the final working version at this stage

```
class person {

    private $defaults = [
        'post_types'        => [],
        'number'            => 1,
        'use_referrers'     => true,
        'in_same_term'      => false,
        'include'           => [],
        'exclude'           => [],
        'taxonomy'          => 'category',
        'include_children'  => true,
        'previous'          => true,
        'boundary_posts'    => false,
        'anchor_text'       => '%anchor',
        'post_link_text'    => '%text',
        'separator'         => '</br>',
        'span_separator'    => '</br>',
        'span_text_prev'    => 'Older post: ',
        'span_text_next'    => 'Newer post: ',
        'span_text_oldest'  => 'Oldest post: ',
        'span_text_newest'  => 'Newest post: ',

    ];

    public $current_post;
    public $is_referred_post    = false;
    public $is_author_referrer  = false;
    public $is_search_referrer  = false;
    public $is_tax_referrer     = false;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->init();

    }

    public function init() {

        $this->getCurrentpost();
        $this->referrers();

    }

    public function getCurrentpost() {

        return $this->current_post = get_queried_object();

    }

    public function referrers() {

        //Set is_author_referrer if query_var aq is set
        if( isset( $_GET['aq'] ) ) {

            $this->is_author_referrer = true;

        }

        //Set is_search_referrer if query_var sq is set
        if( isset( $_GET['sq'] ) ) {

            $this->is_search_referrer = true;

        }

        //Set is_tax_referrer if query_var tq is set
        if( isset( $_GET['tq'] ) ) {

            $this->is_tax_referrer = true;

        }

        //Set is_referred_post if the current single post has one of the query_vars in the URL
        if( $this->is_author_referrer || $this->is_search_referrer || $this->is_tax_referrer ) {

            $this->is_referred_post = true;

        }

    }

}
$a = new person();
```